# Adding a custom object for Out-GridView column

Tags: powershell, object, gridview

Let's say I have :

```
$installed_apps = invoke-command -computername P1184CDC -scriptblock {
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"| ? DisplayName -ne $null
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | ? DisplayName -ne $null
}


$installed_apps | Out-GridView -wait
```

This returns all the installed apps (32bit for the first command and 64bit for the command containing wow6432node) in a nice gridview:

[image]

I'm trying to add an "Architecture" column to the results, so i can identify all 64 bit objects returned from the command:

```
 Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"| ? DisplayName -ne
```

and all 32 bit objects returned from the command :

```
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | ? DisplayName -ne $null
```

Right now they are all together but it would be nice to be able to sort them by 32bit or 64bit type.

I think I have to use New-Object PsObject like for example:

```
$architecture = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 
Architecture = "x86"
}
```

in a ForEach loop but i'm far from comfortable with how to set it all together with the apps returned from the command. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will add an 'Architecture' property to the returned objects (and, hence, a corresponding column in the GridView):

```
$installed_apps = invoke-command  -scriptblock {
    Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | 
        Where-Object DisplayName -ne $null |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Architecture -Value "64-bit" -PassThru

    Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\wow6432node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | 
        Where-Object DisplayName -ne $null |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Architecture -Value "32-bit" -PassThru
}


$installed_apps | Out-GridView -wait
```

Incidentally, the *wow6432node* node is where 32-bit apps read/write, not 64-bit.

Comment: Nice, i was trying to do a whole new object with all the properties but this is as simple as add-member. I will remember that. Thanks a lot and you're right I got them mixed up since wow6432node had a program saying 64bit in it's DisplayName but it's the other way around.